# algorithm:insetion to Binary Search Tree

Tags: algorithm

How can I compare between **2 point** (*both of them have **3 dimension***) to insert them in Binary Search Tree? thanks

Comment: You define a comparator that suits your needs and use that to break those 3 dimensions down to 1? There is no "natural" order over R^n for n > 1 comparable to how there is a natural order over numbers, so it's up to you to define an order that fits with your requirements. The reason is that the elements of R^n have "direction" in addition to magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

Treating each point as a tuple of three elements and comparing them lexicographically looks like a reasonable choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement any algorithm you want provided that it indeed defines an order (that is, it provides a [strict weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html)). There are many ways to do this, the exact way you will want to use will depend on your particular problem.

The simplest way will be to compare the first coordinate, if it is equal, then to compare the second coordinate, and if it is equal too, then compare the third. (The standard comparator for `std::pair` works in a similar way.)

You may reverse the order of coordinates considered, or for example compare by distance from the origin and only then by coordinates, or invent even a more advanced ways to do this.